# Existence of a unique solution and maximal area

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the IVP:
>   $$\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y)~,~y(0)=y_{0},$$
>   where $f(t,y)$ is a bounded function, continuous on the set $\Omega(t,y)=\{ |t| < a , |y-y_{0}| < b   \}$ and satisfies a Lipschitz condition there with Lipschitz constant $K.$
>   Find a condition which will ensure that a unique solution will exist inside $\Omega$ and that the condition has a maximal area on $\Omega.$

**My approach.** The solution of the IVP is given by
$$y(t)=y_{0}+\int_{0}^{t} f(s,y(s))~ds.$$
$$\implies | y(t) - y_{0} | \leq  \int_{0}^{t} | f(s,y(s))|~ds \leq  M \cdot |t|,~~\text{where}~M=\max_{s}|f(s,y(s))|.$$
Since in $\Omega,~|t| < a,$ we have
$$| y(t) - y_{0} | < a \cdot M.$$
Also, incorporating the Lipschitz condition in the second argument yields
$$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)| \leq K \cdot |x-y|.$$

I don't know how to continue from here onwards. Any help is much appreiciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I(t) = \begin{cases} [t,0], & t<0 \\ [0,t], & t \ge 0 \end{cases}$. Let $u$ and $v$ be two solutions on $(-a,a)$. Then, as you correctly write,

$$u(t) = y_0 + \int \limits _{I(t)} f \big(s,u(s) \big) \ \Bbb d s \qquad \text{and} \qquad v(t) = y_0 + \int \limits _{I(t)} f \big(s,v(s) \big) \ \Bbb d s ,$$

so that

$$\sup _{|t|<a} |u(t) - v(t)| = \sup _{|t|<a} \left| \int \limits _{I(t)} f \big(s,u(s) \big) - f \big(s,v(s) \big) \ \Bbb d s \right| \le \sup _{|t|<a} \int \limits _{I(t)} \Big| f \big(s,u(s) \big) - f \big(s,v(s) \big) \Big| \ \Bbb d s \le \\
\sup _{|t|<a} \int \limits _{I(t)} K \ |u(s) - v(s)| \ \Bbb d s \le K \sup _{|t|<a} \sup _{s \in I(t)} |u(s) - v(s)|  \int \limits _{I(t)} \Bbb d s = K \sup _{|t|<a} \sup _{s \in I(t)} |u(s) - v(s)| \ t \le \\
aK \sup _{|s|<a} |u(s) - v(s)| $$

Looking only at the endpoints of this chain of inequalities, and assuming now that $u \ne v$, it follows that $\sup _{|s|<a} |u(s) - v(s)| \ne 0$ so we may divide by it, thus obtaining $1 \le aK$. What we have obtained, then is the following implication: if the problem does not have a unique solution, then $aK \ge 1$. It follows then that **if $aK < 1$ then the problem has a unique solution**.